# Copied Joomla 1.5.12 across to new host server. Front End OK. Admin fails

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, joomla1.5

I've been fishing through answers to similar problems, but none seem to address the issue we currently have. To sum up what has occurred this far:

- Client has a website running joomla v1.5.12 (yeah, we know it's old...)
- Site was very slow so upgraded hosting package to higher specs.
- Took an FTP backup of the original site beforehand and then copied it accross.
- Site works on the front end as normal. Sends emails and is both cosmetically and visually sound.
- However, admin pages keep showing errors in the same vein as the following:

`JFolder::folder: Path is not a folder`

and

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \\**servername**\Domains\e\sitename.com-XXXnumbersXXX\user\htdocs\libraries\joomla\language\language.php on line 712
```

The errors keep popping up throughout portions of the admin side of things. Trying to add or edit any new articles results in a blank screen. Editing other modules results in the above foreach() errors. The foreach() functions are being passed filepaths, but I can't figure out their values (I'm not much of a PHP dev).

Why would the front end work without any problems and only the backend areas have an issue?

Any ideas of how I should go about troubleshooting this?

Many thanks in advance,
D

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have issues with a new Joomla install I check the following things:

1. Are file paths set correctly?
2. Are the file permissions correct?
3. Are the tmp and log folders writable?
4. Is the .htaccess file set correctly?

You can find the answers to the first three at the following location:

```
Joomla Admin Panel > Help > System Info
```

Hope that helps